# Hovering over image map does not change cursor to hand in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, imagemap

I have an image with a map of two clickable areas. These work as expected on firefox and chrome. In IE, the cursor doesn't change to the 'hand'. I am able to click and navigate fine. So most things seem alright. The only thing that doesn't happen is the change of cursor into the 'hand'. Any idea what I am missing?

```
  <td><img id="shop-icon-image"  src="img3/shop-icon.png" usemap="#shopiconmap" />
        <map name="shopiconmap">
            <area shape="rect" coords="3,75,43,88" href="http://domain/page" /> 
            <area shape="rect" coords="44,75,82,88" href="http://domain/page" /> 
        </map>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got past this after 4 non productive hours :(

A reset stylesheet I was using had a 'body{cursor:default}' in it. But this shouldn't have been an issue because I had the 'area {cursor:pointer}' defined. But IE isn't overriding this. Seems like a bug to me. In the developer toolbar the cursor:default is struck across indicating that it has been overridden but in reality its not. Taking that line out (cursor:default) is what fixed it. phew!

Comment: `body {...}` and `area{ ... }` have the same specificity. Another workaround you could have applied was making the `area` selector more specific, eg `body area{ ... }`.

Comment: hmm.. then it will be worth noting that the specificity is behaving different in different browsers. The cursor pointer showed up in chrome and firefox even without adding the 'area {cursor:pointer}'. Not sure how that worked.  Also if they are supposed to have same specificity, not sure why IE developer tools show it as being overridden. Lots of unknowns here.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to CSS:

```
area
{
 cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Comment: Did not help. Cursor still doesn't change to 'hand'

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
area {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Did not help. Cursor still doesn't change to 'hand'.

Comment: Worked for me in IE9.

Comment: Thanks Roddy. True, it works fine on its own. This is how I started debugging too. Started with an empty html file and added imagemap to it and the cursor came out fine on IE. That told me that problem was in my stylesheets. Debugged a bit and found why. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

adding

```
<area href="javascript:void(0)">
```

solved my case without adding additional style "cursor:pointer"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop it actually doing the navigation

```
<area href="#" onClick="return false">
```

This works when using with Angular JS